# How to add sqljdbc_auth.dll to my maven project

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, netbeans, jdbc

I am trying to establish connection to a database. It's a simple project with using maven.

I have problems with `sqljdbc_auth.dll`

I have added mssql jdbc driver and added a dependency in `pom.xml`

```maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my try block

```java
try {
    // Establish the connection. 
    SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
    ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);
    ds.setServerName("BUILDSRV");
    ds.setDatabaseName("master");
    ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);
    con = ds.getConnection();       
}
```

and I get this error

```
    21.11.2012 18:07:04 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
    WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in       java.library.path
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
```

I have my `sqljdbc_auth.dll` but I don't need to put it to my `C:\windows\...`
I need to add it in my project from maven. How can I do this?

I tried to add it to the `pom.xml` but it doesn't work

```maven
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifacts>
                <file>target</file>
                <type>dll</type>
            </artifacts>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I got another error while building

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.1:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) on project mavenproject1dbconnect: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.1:attach-artifact for parameter file: Cannot configure instance of org.codehaus.mojo.buildhelper.Artifact from target -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: how do you intend to use your application, is it a webapp or a standalone deployment ?

Comment: obviously you cannot add the dll in your jar, if it were possible, it would come in the jdbc jar itself in the first place, saving you all the trouble. 
we may have a solution which depends on how you intend to use your app

Comment: not web. but a i can't say that it will be standalone, becouse i don't understand what it mean )

Comment: i mean to say how you do you start your program. like `java MyClass` or `mvn exec:java ... ` or in some webcontainer. and how do you distribute your project, distribute as a jar ?

Comment: now i start java myclass in netbeans ide. but in future i will have a lot of modules

Comment: The error message these others point refers to java.library.path , If it is a DLL it probably should be updated to the system OS environment"path"! Or run with local system command "path" append of the DLL along with the java command in the start .bat.   in a server such as e.g. Tomcat you would assign that to path in something like it's setenv.sh or setenv.bat if there is not a special element for it in the server.xml.     https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadlibrary-windows.asp

Comment: org.codehaus.mojo.buildhelper.Artifact.  <file>target</file>.   target should be a filename

Answer (score 1):

Based on information found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409446/3410989), you could do it by injecting the dll into `java.library.path` at runtime.

*I've had this running in production for a few years now with no problem on Java <= 8. Never really used with newer versions though. Quick tests worked with Java 11, not Java 15*

Here's how I'm doing it:

1. Have the dlls stored in your application path. For instance:

```
project_root
├─src (or any other source path structure)
│ └─...packages...
└─extlib
  └─SqlJdbc
    └─auth
      ├─x64
      │ └─sqljdbc_auth.dll
      └─x86
        └─sqljdbc_auth.dll
```

2. Use the following static initialization code in the class that makes JDBC connection *(java <= 11 version)*:

```java
static {
    File file;
    if ("64".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")))
        file = new File("./extlib/SqlJdbc/auth/x64");
    else
        file = new File("./extlib/SqlJdbc/auth/x86");
    String dllPath;
    try {
        dllPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
        synchronized(Runtime.getRuntime()) {
            final Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
            usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);
            Object o = usrPathsField.get(null);
            String[] paths = o == null ? new String[0] : (String[]) o;
            if (!Arrays.stream(paths).anyMatch(s -> dllPath.equals(s))) {
                String[] usr_paths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
                usr_paths[paths.length] = file.getCanonicalPath();
                usrPathsField.set(null, usr_paths);
            }
        }
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new SQLServerDriver());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468135/3410989), you should be able to push it to at least Java <= 13 using `MethodHandles.privateLookupIn` instead of `ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField`. For instance:

```java
Lookup cl = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(ClassLoader.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
VarHandle usrPathsField= cl.findStaticVarHandle(ClassLoader.class, "usr_paths", String[].class);
Object o = usrPathsField.get();
...
usrPathsField.set(usr_paths);
```

*It's definitely broken with Java 15, as field `usr_paths` doesn't exist anymore in `ClassLoader`*

***At this point, you should be able to run your code from IDE***

3. Deploy the directory containing dlls (i.e. `extlib`) alongside your jar. For Maven, you can use the following in pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/extlib</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>extlib</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

From there, if you need your dlls packed inside your jar, you can do so using `maven-resources-plugin`, and unpack the required dll at runtime, and then force it onto the library path using a variation of above code.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need to use the `maven-helper-plugin` here.
The doc here says you either need to *install* the dll or specify its path in the system variable `java.library.path`.

Look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

UPDATE:
make sure the dll is distributed along with your jar. If you are using a maven,
Put the dll file in your src/main/resources folder. Then make sure the dll ends up outside the jar by excluding it from the package. Follow steps similar to ones outlined [here](http://chandanpandey.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/77/). After this you should have your dll along with your built jar file in `target` directory

Then when you run the app pass system properties as commandline parameter `java -Djava.library.path=.`.

If you prefer not to bother passing parameters via commandline -- you can extract current working directory using `System.getProperty("user.dir"))` and follow steps as stated [here](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/) to set your `java.library.path` to current dir programatically in your `main` method

Comment: no no no. i know it. but it will be local. but i need to add it to project

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to put the dll directly on same level as your main jar.
I suspect your problem has to do with x64 vs x86 versions of dll.
Are you sure your versions align?

I'm using this dep:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1.jre8-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

And the dll:

mssql-jdbc_auth-9.1.1.x64-preview.dll

for my 64 bits project and it works fine