# How to debug loadLibrary to understand why not loading a DLL?

Tags: java, tomcat, loadlibrary

I'm trying to load a DLL with a static block on my servlet definition like this:

```
    String ehrViewerExternalNativeLibs = "webapps" + pathSeparator +
                                         "ehr-viewer" + pathSeparator +
                                         "WEB-INF" + pathSeparator +
                                         "classes" + pathSeparator +
                                         "extlib";

    try {
        String catalinaHome = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        String defaultLibraryPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        String sharedLibraryPath = catalinaHome + pathSeparator + ehrViewerExternalNativeLibs;

        if (catalinaHome != null) {
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", defaultLibraryPath + ";" + sharedLibraryPath);
            String curPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
            logger.info(curPath);
            System.loadLibrary("awj2k");
            //System.load(sharedLibraryPath + "\\awj2k.dll");
            Class.forName("com.aware.j2k.codec.engine.AwJ2k");
        }
```

I keep getting an error like this:

> Mar 10, 2015 11:17:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet ehrViewerServiceImpl
>
> > java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awj2k in java.library.path
> >         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
> >         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
> >         at com.softmedical.ehrviewer.server.EHRViewerServiceImpl.(EHRViewerServiceImpl.java:121)

The output for the library path is :

> INFO  | 2015-03-10 11:17:27,558 |  - D:\Tomcat-7.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;.;D:\Tomcat-7.0\webapps\ehr-viewer\WEB-INF\classes\extlib

And the content of folder **extlib** is

> awj2k.dll

If I put the DLL in **D:\Tomcat-7.0\bin** it works just fine. What dark spell is going behind the curtains? Why can I load a DLL from the place I want? I see the **java.library.path** is set correctly so why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classloader is probably not using your runtime changes to `java.library.path`. See [Adding new paths for native libraries at runtime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409223/adding-new-paths-for-native-libraries-at-runtime-in-java).

Can you load the library using `System.load` in the servlet's `init`? Something like this.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
  ServletContext ctx = config.getServletContext();
  String libPath = ctx.getRealPath("/") + "\WEB-INF\classes\extlib\awj2k.dll";
  System.load(libPath);
}
```

EDIT: I just realized you asked for a debugging approach. Try defining `java.library.path` to include the dir with `awj2k.dll` in the Tomcat startup config or on the command line. If `System.loadLibrary` works, that would confirm that library path changes at runtime are not effective.

Comment: The article 'Adding new paths' helped me fix my issue. Tested with -Djava.library.path.