# Load OpenCV native library Spring boot application successfully but error is thrown when using

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV with Spring boot. OpenCV jar and its native library are built from the source and placed inside my boot jar. I've extracted them from the jar and loaded successfully, but the error is thrown when using. Here's the summarization of my attempts

- Using OpenCV package from [openpnp](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv). Worked fine, when I try to load the library again with `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`, it throws `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library is already loaded in another classloader`. Removing the second load worked, but since they don't have the version I need, so I have to manually build OpenCV to use.
- Test my OpenCV build (jar and native library) with a console project by manually add them to java.library.path, works fine.
- Try to replicate the code from [nu.pattern.OpenCV](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv/blob/develop/src/main/java/nu/pattern/OpenCV.java) to load my build, modified accordingly. Library loaded without any error, try to load again with `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`, no error. Try using any method of OpenCV, error is thrown.

Here's my code

OpenCVLoader.java

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class OpenCVLoader {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpenCVLoader.class);
    private static final String NATIVE_LIB_NAME = "libopencv_java3411.dylib";

    private static Path extractNativeBinary() {
        Path nativeLibTemporaryPath = null;
        try (InputStream nativeLibInputStream = new ClassPathResource(NATIVE_LIB_NAME).getInputStream()) {
            nativeLibTemporaryPath = new TemporaryDirectory().markDeleteOnExit().getPath().resolve("./" + NATIVE_LIB_NAME).normalize();
            Files.createDirectories(nativeLibTemporaryPath.getParent());
            Files.copy(nativeLibInputStream, nativeLibTemporaryPath);
            return nativeLibTemporaryPath;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return nativeLibTemporaryPath;
    }


    private static class TemporaryDirectory {
        static final String OPENCV_PREFIX = "opencv";
        final Path path;

        public TemporaryDirectory() {
            try {
                path = Files.createTempDirectory(OPENCV_PREFIX);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public Path getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public TemporaryDirectory markDeleteOnExit() {
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    delete();
                }
            });

            return this;
        }

        private void delete(Path path) {
            if (!Files.exists(path)) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(final Path dir, final IOException e) throws IOException {
                        Files.deleteIfExists(dir);
                        return super.postVisitDirectory(dir, e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file, final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                            throws IOException {
                        Files.deleteIfExists(file);
                        return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public void delete() {
            delete(path);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exactly once per {@link ClassLoader}, attempt to load the native library (via {@link System#loadLibrary(String)} with {@link Core#NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME}). If the first attempt fails, the native binary will be extracted from the classpath to a temporary location (which gets cleaned up on shutdown), that location is added to the {@code java.library.path} system property and {@link ClassLoader#usr_paths}, and then another call to load the library is made. Note this method uses reflection to gain access to private memory in {@link ClassLoader} as there's no documented method to augment the library path at runtime. Spurious calls are safe.
     */
    public static void loadShared() {
        SharedLoader.getInstance();
    }

    /**
     * @see <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom">Initialization-on-demand holder idiom</a>
     */
    private static class SharedLoader {
        // Class loader error messages indicating OpenCV is not found on java.library.path
        private static final List<String> errorMessages = Arrays.asList(
                String.format("no %s in java.library.path", Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME),
                String.format("%s (Not found in java.library.path)", Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)
        );

        private Path libraryPath;

        private SharedLoader() {
            try {
                System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            } catch (final UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {

                /* Only update the library path and load if the original error indicates it's missing from the library path. */
                if (ule == null || !openCVNotFoundInJavaLibraryPath(ule.getMessage())) {
                    throw ule;
                }

                /* Retain this path for cleaning up the library path later. */
                this.libraryPath = extractNativeBinary();

                addLibraryPath(libraryPath.getParent());
                System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

            }
        }

        /**
         * Check if any error fragment is contained in the errorMessage
         * @param errorMessage the message to check
         * @return true if any error fragment matches, false otherwise
         */
        private boolean openCVNotFoundInJavaLibraryPath(String errorMessage) {
            for (String errorFragment : errorMessages) {
                if (errorMessage.contains(errorFragment)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Cleans up patches done to the environment.
         */
        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            super.finalize();

            if (null == libraryPath) {
                return;
            }

            removeLibraryPath(libraryPath.getParent());
        }

        private static class Holder {
            private static final SharedLoader INSTANCE = new SharedLoader();
        }

        public static SharedLoader getInstance() {
            return Holder.INSTANCE;
        }

        /**
         * Adds the provided {@link Path}, normalized, to the {@link ClassLoader#usr_paths} array, as well as to the {@code java.library.path} system property. Uses the reflection API to make the field accessible, and maybe unsafe in environments with a security policy.
         *
         * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/15409223">Adding new paths for native libraries at runtime in Java</a>
         */
        private static void addLibraryPath(final Path path) {
            final String normalizedPath = path.normalize().toString();

            try {
                final Field field = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
                field.setAccessible(true);

                final Set<String> userPaths = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList((String[]) field.get(null)));
                userPaths.add(normalizedPath);

                field.set(null, userPaths.toArray(new String[userPaths.size()]));

                System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + File.pathSeparator + normalizedPath);

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get permissions to set library path");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get field handle to set library path");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ObjectDetectionService.java

```
public class ObjectDetectionService {
    static {
        OpenCVLoader.loadShared(); // loaded fine,
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); //try to load 1 more time, no exception is thrown
        Mat testMat = new Mat(); // UnsastifiedLinkError;

    }
}
```

stack trace

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-06 10:02:18,639 ERROR [restartedMain] --- [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication][SpringApplication.java:837] Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectDetectionService' defined in file [/Users/minhtus/personal/ppr/build/classes/java/main/com/fptu/swp/ppr/detection/service/ObjectDetectionService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.Application.main(Application.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:23)
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.detection.service.ObjectDetectionService.<clinit>(ObjectDetectionService.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: are missing any so(sharedobject) files?

Comment: @silentsudo I'm on macOS, my native file is .dylib. There're only a jar and a dylib file. As I said, I've tested with a console project and it worked fine so I don't think I missing any files.

Comment: can you try disabling devtools?

Comment: @silentsudo Wow that works, you saved my day. Could you answer with a brief explanation so I can mark it accepted? And also, why the OpenCV package by openpnp worked with devtools but mine didn't? Thank you

Comment: I believe restart feature is only available to classpath file changes, native classes are loaded when application boots up,  but still i do not have a concrete answer to this. Glad it helped have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was disabling devtools as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

you have to include appropriate `OpenCV dlls` to your project.
the easiest way is to package your code into a jar file and putting `OpenCV dlls` in the directory in which your jar file is placed. this way they are included in your classpath automatically.